# I am going to the dentist at 5.30. (phrase meaning)

Tags: phrase-meaning

> I **am going to the dentist at 5.30**. I made the appointment two weeks ago.

Does it mean that he has the appointment at 5.30 or he is going out from his work or home at 5.30? I suppose he is going out at that time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a US English speaker, I think it's ambiguous, but if I heard it, I would assume the appointment was at 5:30, because "going to the dentist"  means "having an appointment with the dentist", not so much "embarking on a trip for the purpose of seeing the dentist".

If the speaker just meant he was going out, I would expect him to say "I am **leaving for** the dentist at 5:30."

(By the way, we write times in US English   with the hour and minute separated by a colon, like **5:30**, not  a dot like in *5.30*.)

Comment: In UK English, you'll often see hours/minutes separated by a colon these days, e.g. in timetables, but not always. As recently as 1983 the railways used a dot/period/full stop `22.07` (10:07 PM for Americans). Before the 24 hour clock was introduced in 1965 the railways used AM/PM (shown in lowercase at the top of column to disambiguate e.g.`p.m.` and the actual train time with no leading zeroes and just a space like `3 5` (03:05 or 15:05 these days). I would say the dot or space is still OK in the UK in the present day. The internal timetables for the staff might be more exact e.g. `12 17½`